# Is there a method in Flutter to open Android's (and iOS's) built in Bluetooth menu

Tags: flutter

I am currently developing an application with Flutter, I want to add bluetooth support to it, I was thinking that it could be cool to use Android's built in bluetooth menu to choose which bluetooth device to pair with instead of developing my own, but is it possible ?

I have searched on google but found no answer (let me know if I didn't searched enough), would be cool if someone could enlighten this topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [system_setting](https://pub.dev/packages/system_setting) package.

Here's an example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:system_setting/system_setting.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _jumpToSetting,
        child: Text('Goto setting'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
));

_jumpToSetting() {
  SystemSetting.goto(SettingTarget.BLUETOOTH);
}
```

Comment: Now is 2021.3.31.This package will make flutter build throw a err:`Execution failed for task ':system_setting:verifyReleaseResources'.`,but flutter run will be fine.I dont know why.

Answer (score 3):

https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent is discontinued

https://pub.dev/packages/intent is not nullsafe support

https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus its ok

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app_settings/app_settings.dart';
import 'package:android_intent_plus/android_intent.dart';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      const AndroidIntent(
        action:
            'android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE',
      ).launch().catchError(
          (e) => AppSettings.openBluetoothSettings());
    } else {
      AppSettings.openBluetoothSettings();
    }
  }
  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of [system_setting](https://pub.dev/packages/system_setting) package use [app_setings](https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings) package.

```
ElevatedButton(
        child: Text("Bluetooth"),
        onPressed: () {
          AppSettings.openBluetoothSettings();
        },
      )
```

This Code will take you to the Bluetooth Settings of Android and iOS. More examples in https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings/example

Comment: On the following link, it says that bluetooth is supported by android only.
https://github.dev/spencerccf/app_settings

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to open the Android Bluetooth config screen when the user clicks a button in Flutter, is that right?

To achieve that you can use the plugin android_intent [1] to open the settings screen

```
AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
   action: 'android.settings.BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS',
);
await intent.launch();
```

You may want to check if the platform is android before to do that in case that you export the app to iOS.

[1] https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent

Comment: I checked that out and it looks cool but as I'd like my app to be fully compatible with iOS I'm gonna void to use it.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I assume that you wan android only from your question. But the other solution posted here should be safer.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough in my question, i'll make sure to be clear enough the next time.